# Actualización de datos en Crystal Reports V.B

Tags: crystal-reports

estoy programando en Visual Basic. tengo una base de datos, cree un **Crystal Report**, por ende al crear un reporte hay que crear una conexión y de igual forma hay crear un **DataSet**.
sucede que la base de dato contiene todos los datos y el **Crystal Report no actualiza los datos**

Comment: Deberías de adjuntar el código con el que estás trabajando para que se pueda ver que es lo que está fallando.

Comment: Gracias por la información